# Discrete metric space proof

Tags: proof-writing, metric-spaces

Suppose that $A \neq \emptyset$ is a set. Let $d: A \times A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a metric defined as follows:

For $a, b \in A$,  $d(a, b) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr} 
      1 & \mbox{if } a \neq b \\
      0 & \mbox{if } a = b  
      \end{array}
\right.$

Determine the closed and open subsets of this metric space $(A, d)$.

I am new to metric spaces and have been trying for hours but I cannot figure out this problem. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: HINT: If $0<r\le 1$, and $a\in A$, what is $B(a,r)$, the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $a$. You should know that by definition it is $\{x\in A:d(a,x)<r\}$, but exactly what points of $A$ are in this set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any $x \in A$ and consider the open ball of center $x$ and radius $1/2$, i.e.,  $B(x, 1/2)$. By the definition of the metric $d$, $B(0, 1/2)=\{x\}$. Therefore, every point is an open ball, and every subset of $A$ is open (why?).

From this fact, is easy to find the closed sets.

Comment: I thought about it but I am still not sure how to find the closed sets. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: A set is closed iff its complement is open. If every set is open, then...

Comment: Ahhh! I see. I didn't know about this theorem "a set is closed iff its complement is open". Thank you!